# how to send notification to different different customer as per their order in android sql?

Tags: android, sql, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I send a notification from server to different user who is using my app for example if I need to send a notification to user1 about their order that your order is on your way or it will take 30 minutes to reach, how can I do that?? I think about the notification but how it is possible from the server through my app ??

I am new in android, So kindly help me.

Comment: read about FCM (Firebase messanging)

Comment: You have to be more specific before asking here.First point out your task and then ask ask one by one,because here your questions covers lots of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into firebase cloud messaging.  It used to be called Google Cloud Messaging.  Its a way for your server to be able to send messages to individual users.  And so long as you don't use the other services in Firebase, its free.

Comment: kindly provide official link so that i can use that

Comment: yeah i m searching this only